# How do I get the bash date script to return a day of the week relative to a non-current time?

Tags: linux, bash, date

Using bash date, I can get it to return a day of the week relative to the current time.

```
date --d='last Sunday' #Returns date of the Sunday before today
```

I can also get it to return a day relative to some other date

```
date --d='02/1/2012 -2 days' #Returns date two days before Feb. 1, 2012
```

but how can I get it to return the day of the week relative to some non-current time? What I want to do is:

```
date --d='Sunday before 02/1/2012' #Doesn't work! I want Sunday before Feb. 1
```

If possible, I would even like to be able to chain strings so that I can reference relative days from the new date:

```
# Should return 2 days before the Sunday before Feb. 1, 2012
date --d='Sunday before 02/1/2012 - 2 days'
```

Though this chaining is not as important. Is there some way for bash date to return a day based on the relative day of the week?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a little day number arithmetic:

```
base="02/1/2012"
feb1_dayofweek=$( date -d $base +%w )
target_dayofweek=0   # sunday
date -d "$base - $(( (7 + feb1_dayofweek - target_dayofweek) % 7 )) days"
```

result:

```
Sun Jan 29 00:00:00 EST 2012
```

Answer (score 4):

Well with bash it can be done with some loop (e.g. get the date you want to use as a reference into a variable in Unix %s format than decrement it with 24*60*60 check if its Sunday, and print it if it's true...)

Or you can set up something like this with `awk`

```
 awk -v BASEDATE="2011 02 02" -v DIW="Sun" -v BEF="2"
       'BEGIN { ct=BASEDATE " 00 00 00"
                ct=mktime(ct)
                while (strftime("%a",ct) != DIW) { ct-=24*60*60 }
                ct-=BEF*24*60*60
                print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a",ct)
              }'
```

[You can see it in action here](http://ideone.com/TYQ2l). Almost. As [ideone](http://ideone.com/) (which I adore) does not allow passing command line variables to `gawk` (or I was lazy to figure it out ;-)), I had to embed them to the `BEGIN` block too.

If you want to you can convert the above to a `datecalc.awk` (with `!#/usr/bin/gawk -f` script which uses `ARGV[n]` variables instead of `-v` supplied ones so you can call it easily from your shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do if you have [libfaketime](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/) installed.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libfaketime.so.1
$ FAKETIME='2012-02-01 00:00:00' date --d='last sunday'
Sun Jan 29 00:00:00 EST 2012
```

You can chain it by setting FAKETIME dynamically.  This will get messy, but will work:

```
$ FAKETIME=$(FAKETIME='2012-02-01 00:00:00' date --d="last sunday" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') date --d="-2 days"
Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 EST 2012
```