# Shell Script to Get Date In Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, scripting

I am new to Shell scripting.

I want to write a script to get any random Date from the user in the format YYYY:MM:DD and echo (display) date of tuesday and friday of previous week.

For Example if I give Input Date as `2013-12-11`.
The output should be

```
date1= 2013-12-06
date2= 2013-12-10
```

or

Input Date as `2013-12-07`

Output

```
date1= 2013-12-03
date2= 2013-12-06
```

Comment: Your expected input/output don't seem consistent.  What's your definition of _week_, i.e. when does a week begin according to you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the bash date script to return a day of the week relative to a non-current time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203747/how-do-i-get-the-bash-date-script-to-return-a-day-of-the-week-relative-to-a-non)

Comment: Tue and Fri of previous week or most recent Tue and Fri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
input=2013-12-11
lastTues=$(date -d "$input -$(date -d "$input +5 days" +%u) days" +%Y-%m-%d)
lastFri=$(date -d "$input -$(date -d "$input +2 days" +%u) days" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

This command first works out how many days there are between the input date and last Tuesday (or Friday), call this `X`. It then runs `date -d "inputDate -X days"` to calculate the new date.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DateTime;

sub tuefri {
    my ($year, $month, $day) = split /[^0-9]/, shift;
    my $date = 'DateTime'->new( year  => $year,
                                month => $month,
                                day   => $day,
                              );
    $date->subtract(days => 7);
    my @result;
    until (2 == @result) {
        push @result, $date->ymd if grep $_ == $date->day_of_week, 2, 5;
        $date->add(days => 1);
    }
    return @result
}

my $i = 1;
print 'date', $i++, "= $_\n" for tuefri(shift);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [python](/questions/tagged/python) solution using the `python-dateutil` module:

```
import fileinput
from dateutil.relativedelta import TU, FR, relativedelta
from datetime import date

for line in fileinput.input():
    d = date(*(map(int, line.rstrip().split('-'))))
    print(d + relativedelta(weekday=FR(-1)))
    print(d + relativedelta(weekday=TU(-1)))
```

Run it like:

```
python script.py <<<"2013-12-11"
```

That yields:

```
2013-12-06
2013-12-10
```